# Как правильно произносить даты: тысяча или одна тысяча?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, числительные

Учитель литературы и учитель русского языка моей школы постоянно исправляют нас, когда мы вместо "одна тысяча девятьсот восемьдесят четыре" говорим "тысяча девятьсот восемьдесят четыре". Однако при поиске ответа в интернете я нахожу, что говорить "одна" неуместно, так как это загружает речь, и при упоминании о "тысяче" мы имеем в виду "одну тысячу" и никак иначе.
Так кто же всё-таки прав: интернет или же учителя?

Answer (score 4):

1) **ТЫСЯЧА**, I. числ. колич. Число 1000. **От тысячи** отнять сто. **К тысяче** прибавить двести. // Количество 1000. Т. рублей. Проехал **тысячу километров.**

2) В грамматике дается такая запись составного **количественного** числительного: **(одна) тысяча девятьсот восемьдесят шесть.** Из этого можно сделать вывод, что слово  "одна" используется при необходимости, например в финансовых документах во избежание их подделки. Но с точки зрения семантики такая запись **не несет в себе новой информации.**

3) В датах используется **порядковое числительное**, например: тысяча девятьсот семнадцатый год, там слово "одна", **очевидно, является лишним.**  Тем не менее оно употребляется, но мне такое сочетание кажется **архаичным или стилизованным под старину или высокий стиль.**

4) В Нацкорпусе сочетание ***в одна тысяча*** встречается значительно реже, чем **в тысяча** (частотность 50:410).

― Они поссорились **в тысяча** восемьсот восемьдесят пятом году и с тех пор не встречаются, не говорят друг с другом даже по телефону. [М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника (Театральный роман) (1936-1937)]

— В гражданскую, **в одна тысяча** девятьсот двадцатом дело было. [Федор Абрамов. Дом (1973-1978)].

Answer (score 2):

Привожу ответы, найденные мной на сайте "ГРАМОТА.РУ"
Общий вывод: в общем случае оба варианта возможны, но о годах: литературный вариант — без слова *одна*, однако и с *одна* грубой ошибки нет.

> [Вопрос № 207990](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=207990)
>   Как правильно писать: Тысяча или Одна тысяча, например, рублей
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   В финансовых документах принято писать: *одна тысяча рублей*.
>
> [Вопрос № 219607](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=219607)
>   как правильно писать: тысяча триста тридцатый год или одна тысяча... ?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Оба варианта корректны.
>
> [Вопрос № 225028](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=225028)
>   Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли ошибкой произношение года: в одна тысяча девятьсот сорок пятом году? И если да, то насколько грубой? А может быть, и такое произношение возможно?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Литературный вариант: в тысяча девятьсот сорок пятом году (без слова "одна"). Но грубой ошибки нет.
>
> [Вопрос № 251272](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251272)
>   В связи с наступлением XXI века, как правильно называть года: одна тысяча такой-то год (две тысячи восьмой год) или тысяча такой-то год? Спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Верно: тысяча девятьсот девяносто девятый год; две тысячи девятый год.
>
> [Вопрос № 261090](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=261090)
>   Здравствуйте!
>   Как правильно? (В одна тысяча девятьсот девятом году или в одну тысячу девятьсот девятом году) Благовещенский технологический университет стал полтиехническим. Заранее благодарю!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Правильно: в тысяча девятьсот девятом году.
>
> [Вопрос № 255810](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=255810%20)
>   Подскажите пожалуйста, разрешается ли во фразах типа "одна тысяча человек", опускать слово "одна" ?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Использовать это слово нет необходимости.
>
> [Вопрос № 267063](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=267063)
>   как правильно говорить тысяча рублей или одна тысяча рублей?и почему?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Оба варианта возможны. Тысяча рублей - это и есть "одна тысяча".
>
> [Вопрос № 267273](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=267273%20)
>   Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли привычка некоторых людей читать даты, например, "одна тысяча триста двадцатый год" следствием когда-то бытовавшей нормы русского языка (одна тысяча...) или обычной просторечной ошибкой? Спасибо
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Вряд ли можно считать это ошибкой, скорее - "гиперкорректностью".